# Transferring and installing android studio updates offline

Tags: android, android-studio

I have Android Studio 1.3.2 installed on ubuntu 15.04. I tediously updated the studio and all the extra packages. But now I would be getting a new hard disk so I want to transfer all these updates to new installation.

1. Where does Android stores these updates and new packages.

   2. Can I copy them and use the same updates that are already downloaded on a fresh copy of studio.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The android studio saves its updates in Android folder (which has SDK folder in it). I could copy that :)